# Running text: Pause, Stop

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have `<p>` element:

```
<p id="news_title">Text goes here</p>
```

Which I have made to run text with help this JavaScript:

```
(function(){
var j = 0;
var el = document.getElementById("news_title");
var interval;
function runEngine(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (j===200){
            j=-200;
        }
        el.style.left = j + "px";
        j++;
    },20);
}

window.onload = function(){
    runEngine();
};
})();
```

Marked script working nicely, but I want to pause the text `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` let it continue running. Also, `onclick` I want to stop it for good.

```
el.onmouseover = function(){
   clearInterval(interval);
};  // pausing , working nicely

el.onmouseout = function(){
    runEngine();
};  // also working
```

The `onclick` is not working however. Even though I clear the interval, the `onmouseout` handler causes the text to run again. How can I prevent this?

Comment: So clicking should stop the mouseover/out function for the rest of the time the user is on the page?

Comment: onmouseover it should pause, onmouseout it should continue and onclick i want to stop until refreshing page :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On click, set a flag. Then check the flag in the `onmouseout` handler:

```
var clicked = false;

el.onclick = function() {
    clicked = true;
};

el.onmouseout = function() {
    if (!clicked) {
        runEngine();
    }
};
```

Comment: very cute, how i can not thought , starting to trying , thanks :))